# Convert JSONArray string value into int value

Tags: android, arrays, json

I need to convert the value from key "Quantity" into a int.

Basically I have this:

```
[{"Code":"NV","Quantity":"333"},{"Code":"NV","Quantity":"333"}]
```

Need to convert to this:

```
[{"Code":"NV","Quantity":333},{"Codigo":"NV","Quantity":333}]
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Are you asking how to convert the top JSON to be like the bottom JSON. Or do you just need to convert the value to an `int`?

Comment: Top to be like the bottom

Comment: why you want to do that? even though if you want to do it I would recommend not to do that. Better to parse quantity as integer wherever is required or convert your json into a pojo. [json2Pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your json data in string and setting it in `data` string

```
String data = "[{\"Code\":\"NV\",\"Quantity\":\"333\"},{\"Code\":\"NV\",\"Quantity\":\"333\"}]";

try {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(data);
    Log.d(TAG, "Old JSONArray: " + jsonArray); // [{"Code":"NV","Quantity":"333"},{"Code":"NV","Quantity":"333"}]

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
        int quantityValue = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("Quantity"));
        jsonObject.put("Quantity", quantityValue);
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "New JSONArray: " + jsonArray); // [{"Code":"NV","Quantity":333},{"Code":"NV","Quantity":333}]

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

What I am doing here is just replacing old `Quantity` `string` value with `int` value by using `Integer.parseInt()`

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i); 
    object.put("Quantity", Integer.parseInt(object.getString("Quantity")));
}
```

You will need to replace `array` with the name of your array.

Comment: Since it's a JSONArray I need to do it like:  array.getJSONArray(i).Quantity . But the problem is that  I get an unresolved symbol at Quantity....

Comment: You are correct. My bad. I updated my post. Thank you.